# Rename tag request (yajnopavitam to yagnopavitam)

Tags: support, tags

Can one of the mods rename a tag I created, from [yajnopavitam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yajnopavitam) ([ya**j**nopavitam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/yajnopavitam/info)) to ya**g**nopavitam?

We can leave it as it is too, I'm not too sure if the Sanskrit letter 'ज्ञो' from यज्ञोपवीतम् sounds more like the English 'gyo', 'gno', 'jyo' or 'jno'!!

Ref: [How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag)

Comment: The alphabet sounds like "gnyo", no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I took care of it.  See [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest).

I think "Yagnopavitam" is better than "Yajnopavitam", because usually we spell the word for Vedic rituals as "Yagna" rather than "Yajna" in English.  On the other hand, we usually write the word for knowledge as "Jnana" rather than "Gnana".  Ah, the wonders of transliteration!

Comment: Did we lose the tag information due to the synonym? I don't see the tag usage for the new tag. I expected the old tag help to carry over to the new one.

Comment: @sv. Oh, I guess the system automatically deletes the tag wiki when you do the tag synonyms.  I don't see any way to retrieve it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan i think mods can, try [this link](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/admin/orphan-wikis). Not sure anyways.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thanks, I fixed it.